# YAML file error

Tags: yaml

I keep getting this...

```
 in "<string>", line 1, column 1:
    G-4_Cluster:
    ^
expected <block end>, but found BlockMappingStart
 in "<string>", line 221, column 5:
        Spawn_Entity_On_Hit:
        ^
```

Here's the code.

```
    G-4_Cluster:
    Item_Information:
        Item_Name: "&eG-4 Cluster Bomb"
        Item_Type: 127
        Item_Lore: "&eA cluster bomb that releases|&e10 bomblets upon detonation."
        Sounds_Acquired: BAT_TAKEOFF-1-1-0
    Shooting:
        Right_Click_To_Shoot: true
        Cancel_Right_Click_Interactions: true
        Projectile_Amount: 1
        Projectile_Type: grenade
        Projectile_Subtype: 127
        Projectile_Speed: 12
        Sounds_Projectile: EAT-2-1-28,EAT-2-1-32,EAT-2-1-36
        Sounds_Shoot: FIRE_IGNITE-2-0-0
    Cluster_Bombs:
        Enable: true
        Bomblet_Type: 351~3
        Delay_Before_Split: 40
        Number_Of_Splits: 1
        Number_Of_Bomblets: 10
        Speed_Of_Bomblets: 8
        Delay_Before_Detonation: 40
        Detonation_Delay_Variation: 10
        Particle_Release: BLOCK_BREAK-127
        Sounds_Release: BURP-2-1-0
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Damage_Multiplier: 25
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_Radius: 4
        Sounds_Explode: ITEM_PICKUP-2-1-0
    Extras:
        One_Time_Use: true

Putty:
    Item_Information:
        Item_Name: "&ePutty"
        Item_Type: 404
        Item_Lore: "&eRemote explosives.|&eRight click to throw.|&eLeft click to detonate."
        Sounds_Acquired: BAT_TAKEOFF-1-1-0
    Shooting:
        Cancel_Left_Click_Block_Damage: true
        Cancel_Right_Click_Interactions: true
    Explosive_Devices:
        Enable: true
        Device_Type: itembomb
        Device_Info: 2,10,159,159~14
        Sounds_Deploy: SHOOT_ARROW-1-0-0
        Sounds_Alert_Placer: CLICK-1-1-0
        Sounds_Trigger: SHEEP_SHEAR-1-2-0
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_Radius: 5
        Explosion_Delay: 16
        Sounds_Explode: ZOMBIE_WOOD-2-0-0

C4:
    Item_Information:
        Item_Name: "&eC4"
        Item_Type: 69
        Item_Lore: "&eRemote explosives.|&eRight click to place.|&eLeft click to detonate."
        Sounds_Acquired: BAT_TAKEOFF-1-1-0
    Shooting:
        Cancel_Left_Click_Block_Damage: true
#    Ammo:
#        Enable: true
#        Ammo_Item_ID: 46
#        Take_Ammo_Per_Shot: true
    Explosive_Devices:
        Enable: true
        Device_Type: remote
        Device_Info: 2-1A-TheStabbyBunny
        Sounds_Deploy: CHICKEN_EGG_POP-1-1-0
        Message_Disarm: "&eYou have disarmed an explosive device."
        Message_Trigger_Placer: "&e<victim> has set off your C4!"
        Message_Trigger_Victim: "&eYou have set off <shooter>'s C4!"
        Sounds_Alert_Placer: CLICK-1-1-0
        Sounds_Trigger: SHEEP_SHEAR-1-1-0
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_Radius: 6
        Explosion_Delay: 16
        Sounds_Explode: ZOMBIE_WOOD-2-0-0
#    Extras:
#        One_Time_Use: true

Airstrike:
    Item_Information:
        Item_Name: "&eValkrie AirStrike"
        Item_Type: 75
        Item_Lore: "&eCalls in an airstrike at the|&eposition of the thrown flare."
        Sounds_Acquired: BAT_TAKEOFF-1-1-0
    Shooting:
        Right_Click_To_Shoot: true
        Cancel_Right_Click_Interactions: true
        Projectile_Amount: 1
        Projectile_Type: flare
        Projectile_Subtype: 76
        Projectile_Speed: 10
        Sounds_Shoot: FIRE_IGNITE-2-0-0,FIZZ-2-0-0
    Airstrikes:
        Enable: true
        Flare_Activation_Delay: 60
        Particle_Call_Airstrike: smoke
        Message_Call_Airstrike: "&eFriendly airstrike on the way."
        Block_Type: 144
        Area: 5
        Distance_Between_Bombs: 4
        Height_Dropped: 90
        Vertical_Variation: 10
        Horizontal_Variation: 30
        Multiple_Strikes:
            Enable: true
            Number_Of_Strikes: 5
            Delay_Between_Strikes: 10
        Sounds_Airstrike: ENDERMAN_STARE-2-2-0
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_Radius: 4
        Sounds_Explode: ENDERDRAGON_HIT-2-2-0
    Extras:
        One_Time_Use: true

HGrenade:
    Item_Information:
        Item_Name: "&eHellFire Grenade"
        Item_Type: 402
        Item_Lore: "&eExplodes three seconds after launch."
        Sounds_Acquired: BAT_TAKEOFF-1-1-0
    Shooting:
        Right_Click_To_Shoot: true
        Cancel_Right_Click_Interactions: true
        Delay_Between_Shots: 10
        Projectile_Amount: 1
        Projectile_Type: grenade
        Projectile_Subtype: 46
        Projectile_Speed: 10
        Sounds_Shoot: SHOOT_ARROW-2-0-0
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_Radius: 4
        Explosion_Delay: 60
    Extras:
        One_Time_Use: true

Flashbang:
    Item_Information:
        Item_Name: "&eFlashbang"
        Item_Type: 351~8
        Item_Lore: "&eDisorientates the target upon detonation."
        Sounds_Acquired: BAT_TAKEOFF-1-1-0
    Shooting:
        Right_Click_To_Shoot: true
        Cancel_Right_Click_Interactions: true
        Delay_Between_Shots: 10
        Projectile_Amount: 1
        Projectile_Type: grenade
        Projectile_Subtype: 351~8
        Projectile_Speed: 10
        Sounds_Shoot: SHOOT_ARROW-2-0-0
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_No_Damage: true
        Explosion_Radius: 6
        Explosion_Potion_Effect: BLINDNESS-120-1,SLOW-120-1
        Explosion_Delay: 20
        Sounds_Victim: LEVEL_UP-1-0-0
        Sounds_Explode: ANVIL_LAND-2-1-0
    Extras:
        One_Time_Use: true

SpiderMine:
    Item_Information:
        Item_Name: "&eSpider Mine"
        Item_Type: 343
        Item_Lore: "&eAnti-personnel mine.|&eTriggers a fiery explosion when:|&e- walked into by mobs or players|&e- struck with fists or items|&e- shot by projectiles"
        Sounds_Acquired: BAT_TAKEOFF-1-1-0
    Shooting:
        Right_Click_To_Shoot: true
        Cancel_Right_Click_Interactions: true
    Explosive_Devices:
        Enable: true
        Device_Type: landmine
        Device_Info: 51
        Sounds_Deploy: ORB_PICKUP-2-2-0
        Message_Trigger_Placer: "&e<victim> has triggered your mine!"
        Message_Trigger_Victim: "&eYou have triggered <shooter>'s mine!"
        Sounds_Trigger: ITEM_BREAK-2-1-0,ZOMBIE_UNFECT-2-2-0
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Ignite_Victims: 120
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_Radius: 8
        Explosion_Delay: 8
        Sounds_Explode: FIRE-2-0-0,ZOMBIE_METAL-2-0-0
    Extras:
        One_Time_Use: true

Broodstrikes:
        Enable: true
        Flare_Activation_Delay: 60
        Particle_Call_Airstrike: smoke
        Message_Call_Airstrike: "&eFriendly broodstrike on the way."
        Block_Type: 144
        Area: 5
        Distance_Between_Bombs: 4
        Height_Dropped: 90
        Vertical_Variation: 10
        Horizontal_Variation: 50
        Multiple_Strikes:
            Enable: true
            Number_Of_Strikes: 10
            Delay_Between_Strikes: 10
        Sounds_Airstrike: ENDERMAN_STARE-2-2-0
    Spawn_Entity_On_Hit:
        Enable: true
        Chance: 100
        Mob_Name: "Broodling"
        EntityType_Baby_Explode_Amount: silverfish-false-false-2
        Make_Entities_Target_Victim: true
        Timed_Death: <100>
        Entity_Disable_Drops: true
    Explosions:
        Enable: true
        Explosion_No_Grief: true
        Explosion_Radius: 2
        Sounds_Explode: ENDERDRAGON_HIT-2-2-0
    Extras:
        One_Time_Use: true
```

I do not know how to fix this. Please help! It would be very helpful if you told me how this works. Thank you!
This is extra: dddddddddddddfkhjaldgfhalkjhdfalkjhdflkajhflkajdhflkadhfkljahdflkjhadlkfjhalkdjfhlkajhdfkljahdflkjahdfkljhadlfkjhalkdjfhlakshjdfalkdjhfakljdfhlkajhdflkjahdsflkjasdhflkjahdsflkjahdfklhadklfhalkdjfhklajdfhljkahfdlkjahdfslkjahdfkljahsdflkjahdlkfjhaljkdsfhalkjdfhkljafhlkajdhflkjahdflkl

Sorry, I can't post this without the extra...

Answer (score 0):

Your top-level node is a mapping which contains the keys Putty, C4, Airstrike, HGrenade, Flashbang, SpiderMine and Broodstrikes. However, there is "something" before Putty that ought to be a mapping key:value, but which lacks a key.

My guess that you have inadvertedly indented the first line, so that G-4_Cluster is no longer a key in the top-level mapping.